# why %s supports integer and float in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

In python string formatting %s supports string, integer, and float

```
>>> '%s' % 'a'
'a'
>>> '%s' % 1
'1'
>>> '%s' % 1.1
'1.1'
```

where as %d accepts and formats only integer and %s accepts only %f

```
>>> '%d' % 1
'1'
>>> '%d' % 'a'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str
```

Why is that %s alone accepts all three and even more

Comment: %s stands for a string. Since a string can be any of those, it is possible. And for a %d, since a string value can be always taken as an integer, it is not possible.

Comment: Just as a hint, newer python uses new string formatting `"{} {}".format('hello', 3)`

Answer (score 3):

`%s` explicitly *converts the input to string*. `%s`, `%r` and `%a` are the only three placeholders that convert values. From the [`printf`-style formatting documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting):

> `'s'`
>   String (converts any Python object using `str()`).

So `%s` supports any object, as all Python objects support `str()` conversion. `%d` does not do any conversion.

The other placeholders only support specific types. You probably want to use the [new string formatting syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) instead (via `str.format()` or `f`-strings), where conversion and formatting types have been separated. There `!s`, `!r` and `!a` can be added to first convert the value before formatting, keeping the syntax distinct and clearer that conversion takes place.

You still can't apply the `d` format to strings, of course, you'll have to explicitly convert non-integer input values to integers manually if you want to use a `d` field format.

The `%s` and `!s` string conversion is useful for types that do not otherwise have explicit formatting support. It allows you to accept *any* type of object and still give it some formatting in a template string, even if only to limit the field width or set a text alignment. And only string conversion is universally supported, you can't convert arbitrary objects to integers or floats, for example.